# Printing out document does not print 'åäö'. How do I fix it?

Tags: encoding, special-characters

Im trying to print out a scientific paper I have been working on, but for some reason it does not include the letters 'åäö' (Im from Sweden). The operating system is completely on English (I like it so), so I think it has something to do with my character encoding, but I do not know how to fix it. Any one who do?

Edit:
I think I solved it by simply do:
sudo apt-get install language-pack-sv

Will return later to confirm if it worked after I have tried it.

Edit 2:
Nope it did not work, I instead sold my soule and made a PDF of the document on Windows. Im still interessted in a solution dough..

Comment: Does the PDF display correctly on your screen in Ubuntu? What gets printed out instead of "åäö", nothing or squares or question marks or what?